# ftp.retrbinary timing out while downloading from remote server

Tags: python, ftp, timeout, ftplib

I'm trying to download a file from a ftp server of a client. I have my code that gets the file and it works fine on my laptop. When I run it from the console in my production server which is inside a virtual machine it doesn't work. It also doesnt work on a virtual machine inside of my desktop pc.
The timout happen on ftp.retrbinary

Code:

```
# python > 3.6
from ftplib import FTP

file_csv = 'test.txt'

ftp = FTP(host=hostname, timeout=20)
login = ftp.login(user=user_name, passwd=user_pass)

ftp.set_pasv(False)
ftp.cwd('/csv_files/')

localfile = open(file_csv, 'wb')
ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + file_csv, localfile.write, 1024)
ftp.quit()

localfile.close()
```

I've set the timeout to 20 or the code will never stop unless i force it. The message i get after the time out is

```
~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/socket.py in accept(self)
    203         For IP sockets, the address info is a pair (hostaddr, port).
    204         """
--> 205         fd, addr = self._accept()
    206         # If our type has the SOCK_NONBLOCK flag, we shouldn't pass it onto the
    207         # new socket. We do not currently allow passing SOCK_NONBLOCK to
```

I haven't been able to solve this. Please if someone can help with this, tahnks.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use FTP active mode, unless you have a very specific reason to do so. The active mode usually does not work due to ubiquitous firewalls and NATs.

Use the passive mode instead. To use the passive mode, remove this call:

```
ftp.set_pasv(False)
```

ftplib defaults to the passive mode.

For some background, refer to my article on [FTP connection modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer Martin, I need to use set_pasv or it wont work.
I Solved the problem, my virtualmachine was using the default NAT settings. After switching to another settings it worked.(to 'Use bridged networking' on vmware)